# Angular authentication with ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: asp.net, angular, authentication, asp.net-web-api2

I need to build an Authentication between my Angular frontend and ASP.NET Web Api backend.

The requirements are:

- I need 2 different login pages (1 with a classic login screen and 1 one with a classic login screen + LinkedIn)

I can't find any up to date documentation about how I should make this... 
I looked to https://auth0.com/ but they are using a package that isn't supported any more by my web api version.

My research also learned me that I probably should use Jwt, but i'm having a difficult time to build this in my web api.

Can someone please give me proper documentation? I know there is a build-in authentication but I don't know how good this one is and how you should use them with JWT. Everything I find on the web is out-of-date... .

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is the flow you need to do in order to authenticate a user with linkedin:
**Angular Part:**
1.redirect the user with the requested query params, for example:

```
                   var req = {
                    response_type: "code",
                    client_id: "Your Client ID",
                    redirect_uri: location.origin + location.pathname,
                    state: "DCESFWf45A53sdfKef434"
                };
                window.location.href = linkedinAuthorizationUrl + ObjecttoParams(req);
```

2.After the user is authenticated linkedin will redirect the user back to your **redirect_url** with additional query param named **code**, your angular controller should collect it and send it to your webapi method for the next step.
**WebApi part:**
3.Once you posted the linkedin code to your webapi you need to exchange token with linkedin api(HTTP POST), for example:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()){
string RedirectUrl = providerLogin.RedirectUrl;
//Exchange tokens with linkedin                    
byte[] resultAsBytes = 
wc.UploadValues("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken", new 
NameValueCollection()
              {
              { "grant_type", "authorization_code" },
              { "code", "THE CODE YOU RECEIVED FROM THE CLIENT" },
              {"redirect_uri",RedirectUrl },
              {"client_id", "YOUR LINKEDIN KEY"},
               {"client_secret", "YOUR LINKEDIN PASSWORD"}
                       });

 string resultAsString = 
 System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultAsBytes);
                        var resultAsJson = JObject.Parse(resultAsString);
                        string accessToken = 
 resultAsJson["access_token"].ToString();
 }
```

4.Last part - when you have the access token you need to perform GET request to linkedin's API in order to get the user's details:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()){
wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
var json = wc.DownloadString("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:
(email-address,id,first-name,last-name,picture-url,public-profile-url)?
format=json");
resultAsJson = JObject.Parse(json);
}
```

And that's it! I hope everything is clear and you understand my code. Good luck!